# ajax does not send textbox value of google map lat & lng to controller in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

when i click on google map,i get lat & lng as below:
[image]

and i have some submit textbox and fill those. 
after that,i send form via ajax using below ajax :

```
<script>
    $("#btnAdd").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataa = new window.FormData($("#jobDetails")[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Job/Create",
            data: dataa,
            type: "Post",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "Json",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#result").html(result.id);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("خطا!");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

but in `ActionResult` i get lat & lng 0 as below
[image]

this is my view code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Job.PickUpAddress.Lat, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Job.PickUpAddress.Lat, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "pickLat", @value = "" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Job.PickUpAddress.Lat, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Job.PickUpAddress.Lng, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Job.PickUpAddress.Lng, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "pickLng", @value = "" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Job.PickUpAddress.Lng, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my model:

```
 public double Lat { get; set; }

 public double Lng { get; set; }
```

i dont know why ajax send lat & lng 0. can anybody help me?

Comment: Show your view code, not images of it! And what is your controller method and model - your form controls have `name="Job.PickupAddress.Lat"`, not `name="Lat"`

Comment: And what is the element with `id="jobDetails"`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i assign textbox using `javascript` and per `id` not `name`.it is funny because  when i set textbox value like this `document.getElementById('pickLat').value = "100"', `controller` receive `Lat=100` but when i click on google map,does not send value.

Comment: @StephenMuecke `jobDetails` is the id of my entire form.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it - a form post back its name/value pairs

Comment: @StephenMuecke  i should assign value per `name` not `id`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136725/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mojtaba).

Answer (score 0):

i figure that how solve this.lat and lng are `string` but in model my property was `double`. i changed double to string and question solved.